# React.js component doesn't re-render after submit event done

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm beginning to start learning React.js. So that, I wrote Login Form which we will show when user comes to the page and Home Page that will show when user successfully logged in.

Basically, my project structure is like:

- node_modules
- public
- src

  - components

    - Login.jsx
  - App.js
  - index.js

And the codes are as follow:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './containers/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';

const App = () => (
    <Login />
);

export default App
```

**Login.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from '../containers/Home';

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            username:'',
            password:''
        }
    }


    handleUsernameChanged(event){
        this.setState({username: event.target.value});
    }

    handlePasswordChanged(event){
        this.setState({password: event.target.value});
    }

    isAuthenticated(){
        var userInfo = localStorage.getItem('userInfo');
        if(userInfo != null)
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    render() {
        const isAlreadyAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated();

        return (
            <div>
            {isAlreadyAuthenticated ? <Home /> : 
                (
                    <div>
                        <div className="login">
                            <div className="login-brand bg-inverse text-white">
                                <img src="assets/img/logo-white.png" height="36" className="pull-right" alt="" /> Login Panel
                            </div>
                            <div className="login-content form-input-flat">
                                <h4 className="text-center m-t-0 m-b-20">Great to have you back!</h4>
                                <form>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" text={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsernameChanged.bind(this)}  className="form-control input-lg" placeholder="User Name" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <input type="Password" text={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChanged.bind(this)}  className="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="row m-b-20">
                                    <div className="col-md-12">
                                        <button onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)} className="btn btn-lime btn-lg btn-block">Sign in to your account</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleClick(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:51171/api/user/validate?user_name=" + this.state.username + '&user_password=' + this.state.password;
        console.log(apiBaseUrl);
        fetch(apiBaseUrl)
            .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data[0].status === "1")
                {
                    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
                    this.setState();
                }else{

                }
            })
    }
}


export default Login;
```

I'm facing problem when I login. Login was successful and user information was stored in LocalStorage but component was not re-render and Home page is not showing up.
Home page only shows up when I manually refresh the page after successful logged in attempt.

Your kind advise is deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do this in the constructor this.isAlreadyAuthenticated = this.isAlreadyAuthenticated.bind(this). and also you need to change the state in order for the component to re-render

Comment: replace `this.setState();` with `this.setState({});`

Comment: I have modified and tested but no luck, still not working. Thanks heap for kind suggestion.

Comment: It works now when I changed to used '=>' at my fetch function to be the same context to access the state values. Thanks heap for your kind help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to rerender the component once submit button is clicked, you need to change the state upon form submission. I suggest you keeping `isAlreadyAuthenticated` in your local state. SO your state should look something like this,

```
this.state={
            username:'',
            password:'',
            isAlreadyAuthenticated: false
        }
```

Then when the submit button is clicked set it to true, so that component is rerendered and home component is hsown according to your logic. So your handle submit callback should look like this,

```
handleClick(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:51171/api/user/validate?user_name=" + this.state.username + '&user_password=' + this.state.password;
        console.log(apiBaseUrl);
        fetch(apiBaseUrl)
            .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data[0].status === "1")
                {
                    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
                    // Update the state here, so it triggers a rerender of the component.
                    this.setState({isAlreadyAuthenticated, true})
                    this.setState();
                }else{

                }
            })
    }
```

Make sure to get the state like `this.state.isAlreadyAuthenticated` when you fetch it back.

Comment: Thanks for the kind advise. I have modified and tested. It's ok now. I only modified a bit in my fetch function to be able to access current state value by using '=>'.